# Why can't I select a file in my Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I am trying to select a .txt file from my Chrome app, but it won't let me. Everything is grayed out!
part of my manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
      "serial",
      "notifications",
      {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]}
   ],
   "file_handlers": {
      "text": {
         "types": [
            "text/*"
         ]
      }
```

part of my JS file:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: "openDirectory"},     function() {
  console.log();
});

 chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(chosenFileEntry,     function(writableFileEntry) {
    writableFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
      writer.onerror = errorHandler;
      writer.onwriteend = callback;

    chosenFileEntry.file(function(file) {
      writer.write(file);
    });
  }, errorHandler);
});
```

Comment: Not an answer but I needed to access the filesystem using Chrome and found that Chrome apps are deprecated: https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html. You'll need to consider switching to an extension.

Comment: `type: "openDirectory"` means this is a directory selector, not a file selector.

Answer (score -1):

@Adam Mazzarella is right. Newly-published Chrome apps will only be available to users on Chrome OS. Existing Chrome apps will remain accessible on all platforms, and developers can continue to update them. It is highly encourage for developers to [migrate your Chrome apps](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration) to the web.

From this [documentation](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration):

> Chrome packaged and hosted apps will be discontinued on Windows, Mac, and Linux over the course of now and early 2018. For more information, refer to the August 2016 [Chromium blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html). This transition does not apply to Chrome OS, where Chrome packaged and hosted apps will remain supported and maintained for the foreseeable future.
>
> To transition away from a Chrome packaged or hosted app on Windows, Mac, and Linux, the following options are available.
>
> - Build a web app
> - Build an extension-enhanced web page
> - Build an extension
> - Build a native app

Hope this helps!